# JSLink on Custom Form

Tags: 2016, jslink

Is JSLink exclusive to default forms?

The JSLink field exists on my default forms, like below:

[image: Default form]

However, it does not work when I create a new custom form via SP Designer, as below:

[image: Custom Form]

Is this expected?

How can I add JsLink to a custom form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use designer to create a form - it creates a stone age webpart `DataFormWebPart` that does not have JSLink property. Only XSL Link

Starting form SharePoint 2013, the forms use `ListFormWebPart` webpart. It does have JSLink.

If you want SharePoint Designer to create forms - then follow these steps:

- Create a new form
- Borrow the node `< ZoneTemplate >` from the default form
- Replace your new form's `< ZoneTemplate >` with the one you copied from the out-of-the-box one.

P.S. I don't like the idea of using SharePoint Designer in 2018. There are very few legitimate cases when it's justified, but it's a topic for a different discussion

Comment: Totally agreed. This case specifically is a migrated list where the default form came broken. So idea was to create a new one. Do I have any other options in this case? Recreate the default form somehow?